# How const enum HttpStatusCode works?

Tags: typescript

I know that const enum doesn't compile to javascript.

[image]

And angular exported:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L357

But how it works?

[image]

I tried to search preserveConstEnums in the project, but couldn't find anywhere, how do you do it? :)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveConstEnums

[image]

We have a problem with it:

https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/taiga-ui/blob/main/projects/addon-commerce/enums/currency.ts

[image]

But it works for:

[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-hwmyaf

Answer (score 1):

While their *declarations* are erased, const enum *references* are replaced with their real values at compile-time. E.g.

**.TS**

```
const enum Foo {
  Bar = 100,
  Baz = 200
}

const i = Foo.Bar
```

**.JS**

```js
const i = 100 /* Bar */;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&preserveConstEnums=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgMRCGBvAUDGAIQEMAnGAXhgEYAGWgGnyOIC9KYAme3AX11yhIsAJYcMIAHQlSQA)

---

To preserve const enums, you need to set the `preserveConstEnums` flag for the TypeScript compiler. This can be done either by adding the flag when calling `tsc` from the cli, or as a compiler option in your tsconfig.json.

**tsconfig.json** (add `"preserveConstEnums": true` under your `"compilerOptions"`):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true
  }
}
```

**cli**:

```sh
tsc --preserveConstEnums
```

You can also see this in the TypeScript playground by expanding the TS Config dropdown. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?preserveConstEnums=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgMRCGBvAUDGAIQEMAnGAXhgEYAGWgGnyOIC9KYAme3AX11yhIsAJYcMIAHQlSQA)

Comment: what do you mean? angular when building own packages use preserveConstEnums?

Comment: but searching their project for the --preserveConstEnums flag doesn't find anything

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. See updated answer.

Comment: I mean about: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43516#issuecomment-923107376

Comment: How they are emitted to .d.ts file of @angular/common/http

Comment: My problem - https://stackblitz.com/edit/taiga-starter-jyc65p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The type declarations are always omitted unless you explicitly exclude them by not exporting or by setting the `declaration` option to false

Comment: We have declaration after compile and publish it, but not working for stackblitz ((